# How to combine a dynamic and a static route in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I created routes below, the `story/new` doesn't show it's `story-new.html` template. It always go to `story-view.html` because I got dynamic `:storyID` so `new` consider as a dynamic name.

How to combine them so `/new` will route to the `story-new.html` or I got wrong with my route structure?

```
$routeProvider.when('/story/new', {
 templateUrl: 'js/modules/story-new/story-new.html'
});

$routeProvider.when('/story/:storyID', {
 templateUrl: 'js/modules/story-view/story-view.html'
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unsure this works, but switching them around could solve your problem.

Comment: OMG, Magic!  This works. 
I vote you the shortest answer in Stackoverflow.

Comment: Yea it works but I'm not entirely sure why. Would love to know what the actual logic is when Angular goes through all the routes (I'm guessing it tries to match the ones you defined last first). Also why is @madhured's answer working?

Comment: Because madhured defined `otherwise` at the end of routeProvider?

Answer (score 1):

Check the following plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/pgQu8nwGYrOQusZnThUy?p=preview

Let me know if anything

Comment: It works but not work when without defined `otherwise`

Comment: You should always use `otherwise` since it's possible that someone would manually change a URL, or a template file name might change or be deleted. `otherwise` ensures your user won't be stranded.